# Handling user privileges in a frontend shell application that delegates user management to a dynamics CRM 2011 backend

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, elmah, privileges

I currently have an ongoing project that's basically a frontend for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011. I authenticate the user using their username and password for our own CRM installation and access all data using their privileges. All privilege management, including access control, is done by CRM. There is no user or privilege management done by the frontend itself. There are basically 3 pages: a login page, a main page where everything is loaded dynamically using user controls, and an error page.

I'm currently thinking about throwing an elmah log manager in there so I can check errors more easily without compromising the safety. Naturally, this means placing this behind an administrator wall so it's inaccessible from outside. However, the frontend does not have a separate privilege management system, so I cannot just say "allow adminstrator role, deny*" in my web.config, because there's no administrator role.

I'm currently trying to figure out what the best way to handle this is. I doubt the proper way to handle this is to add a completely separate user management system just for the elmah logs.

Comment: Is this MVC or WinForms?

Comment: It's neither, it's a simple classic ASP.net web application.

Comment: Duh, I meant WebForms, not WinForms, my bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add code in your PageLoad to check to see if the current logged in user has a CRM SystemUser account, and if it does, check to see if it has an Administrator Role.  If it doesn't just redirect to another page or display an error.

Comment: I think this is the best method. I've also thought about it, and even though users cannot access entities they have no right to access, I'll have to check the rights they have so they cannot see the buttons they're not allowed to see.